# How to get value of one tag instead of a full page by ajax - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

If i have this page `page.html`:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Hello World!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And i use Ajax jQuery to get it:

```
$.ajax({

    url:"page.html",
    success: function(data){
    alert(data);    
    }

});
```

How can i get value of `<body>` instead of a full page?

Comment: `$(data).find('body')`

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your result into a jQuery object.

```
$.ajax({

  url:"page.html",
  success: function(data){
    var $html = $(data),
        $body = $html.find('body');
  }

});
```

Comment: `$body`  is an object?

Comment: yes, it's a jquery object. you can get its contents with `$body.html()`;

Comment: i got undefined value

Comment: Check the value of the variable `data`. If it's empty, there's something wrong in your ajax call. And remember, the scope of the variable `$body` is the `success` callback function.